# conditional selection of decimal-format in xslt

Tags: xslt, decimalformat

I'm trying to modify the decimal-format of a stylesheet based on certain information of an XML. More exaclty, I've a XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<REPORT>
   <LANGUAGE>2</LANGUAGE>
   <MYVALUE>123456.78</MYVALUE>
</REPORT>
```

I'm trying to define the decimal format as european if the language is 2, and default otherwse. So I've created the following template

```
<xsl:template match="REPORT">
     <xsl:if test="$language=2">
          <xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select ="format-number(MYVALUE,'###.###,00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So it shows the number in european format or in standard format. But I'm getting the following error

xsl:decimal-format is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!

If I try to put the decimal-format outside the template, then I get the message that the xsl:if is not allowed in this position in the sthylsheet. How can I change the decimal-format based in the XML?

Thanks
Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decimal-format` must be a top-level element, however you can name it and then refer to the name in a conditional construct, perhaps something like the following will work for you.

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="format1" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
<xsl:template match="REPORT">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$language=2">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(MYVALUE,'###.###,00','format1')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="MYVALUE"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element  can only defined directly underneat the  element. After definition you then can use the defined formats in the fromat-number function.

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... namespaces, etc. ...>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="de" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.'/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="us" decimal-separator='.' grouping-separator=','/>

    <xsl:param name="numFormat">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="/REPORT/@language = 2">
               <xsl:text>us</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text>de</xsl:text>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="REPORT">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-numer(MYVALUE, '###.###,00', $numFormat)"/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but since all the document should have the same format, I'd like to define it at the beginning of the document, and not use a choose/when every time I have to show a number.